# SSIS Script Component Destination- split table data to multiple files

Tags: c#, ssis, synchronous, script-component

I am using a data flow task to connect to oledb source and run sql code which produces  millions of rows. Each row is an xml content there is only one column (nvarchar(max)). I connect this to a script component destination, the reason being when the rowcount reaches 10k i want to stop and write to another file.

It works fine when I use a breakpoint, so if there are 100 rows and I want 10 rows in each file when I use a breakpoint it produces 10 files. But, when I run the pacakge without breakpoints  it creates random number of files. For ex: it creates 6 files and 3 of those contains 10 rows and the remaining 70 are split in the other files.

I read through the docs and blogs to see if the input buffer is synchronous, and it seems like it is. i.e each row is processed one at a time at least this is what my understanding is, so I am not sure what is the root cause to this problem? Can someone please shed some light. Below is the code I am using to split files in Script Componenet

```
 [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
 StreamWriter writer;
    int rowCount = 0;
    int rowLimit = 50;
    String RunFileName = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".txt"; 
    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();
        writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(RunFileName, true);
        rowCount = 0;
    }
    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();
        writer.Dispose(); 
    }
    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        if (rowCount == rowLimit)
        {
            writer.Dispose();
            rowCount = 0;
            RunFileName = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".txt";
            writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(RunFileName, true);
        }
        var data = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Row.XMLInnerText.GetBlobData(0, Convert.ToInt32(Row.XMLInnerText.Length)));
        writer.WriteLine(data);
        rowCount++; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, if I wasted anyone's time. The problem was because of the way i created the filename, it started appending to the same file .

```
RunFileName = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".txt";
```